# Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6 (last update) shows blank page

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to lunch jupyter notebook last version with python 3 (everything is updated) but it is giving blank landing page. Moreover, using anaconda (with jupyter older version 5.7.4) it works fine.

- Windows 7 operating system (used pip to install jupyter)

How can I fix this issue?